# Allow access to salesforce from any domain using php

Tags: php

I am a newbie to Salesforce and need to allow access to it using my website.

I have gone through the documentation provided by salesforce but it did not help.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US

Actually I have developed a php website using codeignator and the requirement is, it needs to redirect users to salesforce.com for authorization, after authorization the application returns back to the website and from then I can add users as leads to salesforce directly from my website.

But when I try to connect to sales force as per the documentation given in the above link, it is throwing errors as shown below

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

I have signed up for a development account with salesforce.com but the users using this app will have enterprise edition and each user will have its own salesforce product, so how to implement this using one client_id or say my client_id and my redirect url which is defined in my salesforce account, is very confusing, so I am writing it here.

Please help me with this how to allow access to individual salesforce accounts using php, any help is greatly appreciated, also please let me know if I am not clear with my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better if you post your question at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ 

My suggestion would be create a public website on the salesforce which let users in after authentication. And from your php website direct your users to salesforce public website. That will be an easiest path I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion will give a try there.